# Guest checkout using Pay Now button (dwolla)

Tags: php, dwolla

I've looked through the documentation but cant find an example of how to set AllowFundingSources to "true" using the Pay Now button.

Is Guest Checkout only for the server-to-server checkout?

Is there a complete example of using guest checkout? (not just snippets).

Here is the button code I have:

```
<a data-key="YOUR-KEY-HERE" 
data-tax="0" data-shipping="0" data-amount="941.00"
data-desc="Invoice: WDGR112612" 
data-name="October - November " class="dwolla_button" 
href="http://mysite.com/paym/?type=success">Continue</a>
```

Form code:

```
  <p> <?php
    $key = "YOUR_APPLICATION_KEY";
    $secret = "YOUR_APPLICATION_SECRET";
    $timestamp = time();
    $order_id = 1;

    $signature = hash_hmac('sha1', "{$key}&{$timestamp}&{$order_id}", $secret);
    ?>
    <form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="https://www.dwolla.com/payment/pay"
    method="post">

    <input id="key" name="key" type="hidden" value="abcdefg" />
    <input id="signature" name="signature" type="hidden" value="abcd" />
    <input id="callback" name="callback" type="hidden"
    value="http://www.mywebsite.com/callback.aspx" />
    <input id="redirect" name="redirect" type="hidden"
    value="http://www.mywebsite.com/redirect.aspx" />
    <input id="test" name="test" type="hidden" value="true" />
    <input id="name" name="name" type="hidden" value="Purchase" />
    <input id="description" name="description" type="hidden"
    value="Description" />
    <input id="destinationid" name="destinationid" type="hidden"
    value="812-111-1111" />
    <input id="amount" name="amount" type="hidden" value="1.00" />
    <input id="shipping" name="shipping" type="hidden" value="0.00" />
    <input id="tax" name="tax" type="hidden" value="0.00" />
    <input id="orderid" name="orderid" type="hidden" value="188375" />
    <input id="timestamp" name="timestamp" type="hidden"
    value="1323302400" />

    <button type="submit">Pay Now</button>
    </form>
```

Answer (score 3):

There's actually an easier way of enabling Guest Checkout on a Payment Button...

Simply add the "allow-guest-checkout" attribute to the  tag, as follows:

`<a href="http://www.example.com" class="dwolla_button"  data-key="..." data-tax="0" data-shipping="0.99" data-amount="0.00" data-desc="A button [1]" data-name="Testing mode [1]" data-guest-checkout="true" >A button with GC</a>`

Answer (score 1):

To enable Guest Checkout in an offsite gateway session, you'd want to set the value of "AllowFundingSources" to "true" in the POST request. That's the following line:

```
<input id="AllowFundingSources" name="AllowFundingSources" type="hidden" value="true" />
```

In order to do this, you'll need to be forming a request that looks something like the following:

```
{
  "Key": "testkey",
  "Secret": "testsecret",
  "PurchaseOrder": {
  "DestinationId": "000-000-0000",
  "Discount": 0.00,
  "AllowFundingSources": "true",
  "OrderItems": [
      {
          "Description": "Information about an item",
          "Name": "An item",
          "Price": 5.00,
          "Quantity": 1
      }
  ],
  "Shipping": 0.00,
  "Tax": 0.00,
  "Total": 5.00
  }
}
```

Any updates on this topic will be found [here](http://developers.dwolla.com/dev/docs/gateway/guest).